# How to calculate world_position in Shader

Tags: c++, opengl, vertex-shader

I want to program a shader and I have the position of a vertex and 3 matrices:

- mat4 model-view-projection matrix
- mat4 world transformation of the model
- mat3 world transformation for normals

The output has to be

```
vec3 world_position
```

How can I calculate this?

Comment: If your "world transformation of the model" is a transform from model-space to world-space, isn't it just a matter of using that transformation? `world_transform * in_vertex`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Multiply the vertex position as a `vec4( pos, 1.0f)` with the model matrix to get the world coordinates.

For example,

```
vec4 world_vertex = model_transform * vec4( vertexPosition, 1.0f );

vec3 world_position = world_vertex.xyz;
```

---

EDIT

Apologies for reading the question fleetingly. I assumed the mvp multiplication because it is the typical transformation needed before fragment shader is called. As OP mentioned, vertex position should be multiplied by the model matrix.

Comment: After model-view-projection, you're in clip space. World space is after just applying the model matrix. Might be the world transformation op talks about, but who knows.

Comment: I assume that it is the world transformation matrix (sadly there is no documentation). I just think that it is strange that the worldtransformation matrix is mat4 but the world_position is a vec3

Comment: I don't see anything strange with that. Unless you are using homogeneous coordinates `[world_position, 1]` it is impossible to handle translations. Thats also the reason why world_matrix is a mat4 while normal_matrix is a mat3: Normals don't have to be translated, just rotated.

Comment: ah ok, I am new to this. To the solution is basically what Jadh4v wrote but `model_matrix` instead of `MVP`

Comment: Most probably. But I wouldn't accept it until the matrix is fixed. Comments could be deleted and only the wrong answer remains. Actually, it is even worth: Since a projection is involved, also a perspective divide would be required.

Answer (score 1):

The answer was:

```
vec4 world_vertex = model_matrix * vec4( vertexPosition, 1.0f );

vec3 world_position = world_vertex.xyz;
```